# SpecFlow Selenium run on local webpage with Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I'm learning how to use SpecFlow with Selenium in Visual Studio 2015.  I finished creating a simple webpage that has checkbox on it.  Now I want to use SpecFlow with Selenium to test the checkbox selection.  Since the webpage is HTML file and locally on my computer also Selenium does not have ChromeDriver version correctly, so I have to download the ChromeDriver to locally and copy the exe file to C:\Temp\SpecFlowDemo\packages folder.

Below is the code and I think the problem is using "BinaryLocation".  I've searched online, but most posts I have seen, they use "setBinary" method, but based on the ChromeDriver version I have, "setBinary" does not exist.  So I find "BinaryLocation" is the closest that I can use.  But when I run the test via Visual Studio, it says "OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: the chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directly"  I already copy chromedriver.exe into my C:\Temp\SpecFlowDemo\packages folder.  So not sure what is the issue.

```
    IWebDriver webDriver;
    ChromeOptions optionChrome;

[Given(@"There are five selections avaiable")]
public void GivenThereAreFiveSelectionsAvaiable()
{
    string driverExe = @"C:\Temp\SpecFlowDemo\packages";//my SpecFlow project named SpecFlowDemo created with Visual Studio 2015

    //initialize driver
    optionChrome = new ChromeOptions();
    optionChrome.AddArgument("--allow-file-access-from-files");
    optionChrome.BinaryLocation = driverExe;//setBinary() does not exist

    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(optionChrome);
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"C:\Projects\WebDemo\index.html");//my webpage project
}
```

Comment: use nuget to get your references for selenium webdriver and chromedriver.  it will put everything in the correct place.  you also need to run the project and access you page through the web server and not as an absolute file path.

Comment: thank you.  I was not aware that I could install Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver with NuGet.  Now, no more exception. thanks.